# ASP.NET MVC 2 authorization problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, forms-authentication

I am using a custom Membership Provider.  Everything is working great.  However, in my web.config file I have "deny users" enabled so the entire site is locked down.

This works great.  The user is redirected to the login page.

Now, I have a few controllers/actions that I want to allow anonymous access.  About page, password reset, etc.

The only way I can figure out how to do this is to UNLOCK the entire site, put [Authorize] attributes on every controller and remove them for the controller/actions I want anonymous.

This seems backwards to me.  I prefer to lock everything down by default and unlock what is anonymous.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of alternative ways to implement this, but they all involve using a customized AuthorizeAttribute.  One way to do this would be to have a base controller using said customized AuthorizeAttribute that all of your controllers derive from.  This attribute would be customized to prevent anonymous (and unauthorized) access to an action unless it's controller or the action itself has been decorated with another attribute -- say the AnonymousEnabledAttribute.  All of your controllers would derive from this controller and thus inherit it's standard "no anonymous by default" behavior.  You would then simply decorate the controllers/actions you want to be anonymous with the AnonymousEnabledAttribute -- providing the override for that controller or action.  Or, for a controller, simply don't inherit from the protected controller and all of it's actions become public.

Oh, and your whole site would have to remain open.

```
[OverridableAuthorize]
public abstract class ProtectedController : Controller
{
}

public class MostlyProtectedController : ProtectedController
{
    public ActionResult ProtectedAction()
    {
    }

    [AnonymousEnabled]
    public ActionResult PublicAction()
    {
    }
}

[AnonymousEnabled]
public class ExplicitlyPublicController : ProtectedController
{
    // inherits additional behaviors, but anonymous is enabled by attribute
}

public class PublicByOmissionController : Controller
{
    // doesn't inherit and is thus public -- assuming whole site is open
}

public class AnonymousEnabledAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class OverridableAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization( AuthorizationContext context )
    {
          context.HttpContext.Items["ActionDescriptor"] = context.ActionDescriptor;
          base.OnAuthorize( context );
    }

    public override bool AuthorizeCore( HttpContextBase context )
    {
         var actionDescriptor = context.Items["ActionDescriptor"] as ActionDescriptor;
         if (actionDescriptor == null)
         {
             throw InvalidOperationException( "ActionDescriptor missing from context" );
         }
         var attribute = actionDescriptor
                             .GetCustomAttributes( typeof(AnonymousEnabledAttribute,true)
                             .FirstOrDefault();
         if (attribute == null)
         {
             return base.AuthorizeCore( context );
         }
         return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  So, this would mean the site (as per the web.config) would be totally open but all controllers would be locked down by default so as long as they inherit from the ProtectedController?

Comment: @cbmeeks - correct.  Also, I think using the AuthorizeAttribute (or something derived from it), i.e, MVC security, is definitely preferable to trying to mix WebForms-based security and MVC security.

Comment: ** CAUTION **  The AuthorizeAttribute class must be immutable once it is created.  You can use HttpContext.Items to store the ActionDescriptor, but you absolutely *MUST NOT* store it as an instance field inside the class.  The reason for this is that a single instance of AuthorizeAttribute can be used to process multiple concurrent requests, and by introducing an instance field you now have a race condition in your security code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a location in your web.config file for the controllers that you want to always allow:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        ...
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    ...
    <location path="MyArea/MyController">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this never seems to work.  I've put this in and it still is requiring authorization to anonymous actions.

Comment: @cbmeeks: I don't know what to say. We're using this approach and it works fine for us.

Comment: ** CAUTION **  Trying to mix and match <location>-based security with MVC security is a recipe for disaster.  <location>-based security is meant for file-based resources, such as .aspx pages.  Since Controller classes are type-based rather than file-based, <location>-based security can be bypassed.

Comment: @Levi: Can you elaborate? Since I'm just white-listing the known locations of certain controllers, shouldn't that prevent users who aren't logged in from accessing any of the other controllers? How can this be bypassed?

Comment: In general, it's extremely difficult (nigh impossible) to audit every single route in your application to see which controllers they can eventually activate.  It's well within the realm of possibility that there's another route not within the MyArea area but which matches the path MyArea/MyController/Foo and that this route can be used to hit an arbitrary controller.  In that case, your <location> tag would allow access.  And even if you don't have such a route now, it's possible that a future addition to the route table will trigger it.

Comment: [cont.] This is why we tell developers not to use routes or URLs for security in MVC applications.  It's not dependable and is too difficult to audit.  This is why we created an attribute-based authorization system for MVC in the first place.  That way, regardless of how you get to the controller, you can be assured that the framework will do the right thing.

Comment: @Levi: That is an interesting point. While I don't expect it to be a problem for the project I'm working on, I can see how you it could become an issue for some. Is there a good way to do what the OP asked without having to extend a specific controller class? It seems like it would be easy to forget to extend that class, or to forget to put a specific attribute on every single controller in your project.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - This is a little easier in MVC 3 with the introduction of global filters.  You can implement the system described by tvanfosson, which is pretty much the officially sanctioned way to do this.  Basically, you'd register a custom authorization filter at the global level, and the custom filter would look for the existence of an attribute which specifies that a particular controller or action should be excluded from authorization.  If the attribute doesn't exist, assume authorization must take place and perform it.